# Given component holder class packagename.MainActivity does not implement interface dagger.hilt.internal.GeneratedComponent

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

```
MainActivity does not implement interface dagger.hilt.internal.GeneratedComponent or interface dagger.hilt.internal.GeneratedComponentManager
```

I got this error in runtime

Answer (score 0):

@AndroidEntryPoint Add this , it will work fine,
@AndroidEntryPoint annotation doesn't do anything itself ,it is a marker annotation that allows the Hilt Gradle Plugin to process your code.

```
    @AndroidEntryPoint
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(){
    
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }
}
```