# Given component does not implement interface dagger.hilt.internal.GeneratedComponent?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt

I am developing Android app using jetpack compose and dagger hilt but when I run project I am getting the following exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Given component holder class com.example.readerapp.MainActivity does not implement interface dagger.hilt.internal.GeneratedComponent or interface dagger.hilt.internal.GeneratedComponentManager
                                                                                                        at dagger.hilt.EntryPoints.get(EntryPoints.java:62)
                                                                                                        at dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory.createInternal(HiltViewModelFactory.java:149)
                                                                                                        at dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory.createInternal(HiltViewModelFactory.java:143)
                                                                                                        at androidx.hilt.navigation.HiltViewModelFactory.create(HiltNavBackStackEntry.kt:56)
                                                                                                        at androidx.hilt.navigation.compose.HiltViewModelKt.createHiltViewModelFactory(HiltViewModel.kt:56)
                                                                                                        at com.example.readerapp.navigation.ReaderNavigationKt$ReaderNavigation$1$5.invoke(ReaderNavigation.kt:47)
                                                                                                        at com.example.readerapp.navigation.ReaderNavigationKt$ReaderNavigation$1$5.invoke(ReaderNavigation.kt:37)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:116)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
                                                                                                        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$4$1.invoke(NavHost.kt:150)
                                                                                                        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$4$1.invoke(NavHost.kt:149)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.saveable.SaveableStateHolderImpl.SaveableStateProvider(SaveableStateHolder.kt:84)
                                                                                                        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt.SaveableStateProvider(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:60)
                                                                                                        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt.access$SaveableStateProvider(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:1)
                                                                                                        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt$LocalOwnersProvider$1.invoke(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:52)
                                                                                                        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt$LocalOwnersProvider$1.invoke(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:51)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
                                                                                                        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt.LocalOwnersProvider(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:47)
                                                                                                        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$4.invoke(NavHost.kt:149)
                                                                                                        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$4.invoke(NavHost.kt:142)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:116)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.animation.CrossfadeKt$Crossfade$5$1.invoke(Crossfade.kt:133)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.animation.CrossfadeKt$Crossfade$5$1.invoke(Crossfade.kt:128)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.animation.CrossfadeKt.Crossfade(Crossfade.kt:142)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.animation.CrossfadeKt.Crossfade(Crossfade.kt:73)
                                                                                                        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt.NavHost(NavHost.kt:142)
                                                                                                        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$5.invoke(Unknown Source:13)
                                                                                                        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$5.invoke(Unknown Source:10)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.RecomposeScopeImpl.compose(RecomposeScopeImpl.kt:162)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.recomposeToGroupEnd(Composer.kt:2465)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.skipCurrentGroup(Composer.kt:2733)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:3364)
```

below my ReaderNavigation.kt

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
@Composable
fun ReaderNavigation() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = ReaderScreens.SplashScreen.name) {
        composable(ReaderScreens.SplashScreen.name) {

            ReaderSplashScreen(navController = navController)
        }
        composable(ReaderScreens.LoginScreen.name) {

            ReaderLoginScreen(navController = navController)
        }
        composable(ReaderScreens.ReaderStatsScreen.name) {
            ReaderStatsScreen(navController = navController)
        }
        composable(ReaderScreens.ReaderHomeScreen.name) {
            Home(navController = navController)
        }

        composable(ReaderScreens.SearchScreen.name) {
            val searchViewModel = hiltViewModel<BookSearchViewModel>()
            SearchScreen(navController = navController, viewModel = searchViewModel)
        }
    }
}
```

below my MainActivity.kt

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material.Surface
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import com.example.readerapp.navigation.ReaderNavigation
import com.example.readerapp.ui.theme.ReaderAppTheme
import dagger.hilt.android.AndroidEntryPoint

@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            ReaderAppTheme {
                ReaderApp()


                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme

            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ReaderApp() {
    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize(),
        //.padding(top = 46.dp),
        color = MaterialTheme.colors.background,
    ) {
        Column(
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            ReaderNavigation()
        }

    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun GreetingPreview() {
    ReaderAppTheme {
        //  ReaderApp()
    }
}
```

below my BookSearchViewModel.kt

```
@HiltViewModel
class BookSearchViewModel @Inject constructor(private val repository: BookRepository) : ViewModel() {
    var list: List<Item> by mutableStateOf(listOf())
    var isLoading: Boolean by mutableStateOf(true)
    init {
        loadBooks()
    }

    private fun loadBooks() {
        searchBooks("flutter")
    }

    fun searchBooks(query: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {

            if (query.isEmpty()){
                return@launch
            }
            try {
                when(val response = repository.getBooks(query)) {
                    is Resource.Success -> {
                        list = response.data!!
                        if (list.isNotEmpty()) isLoading = false
                    }
                    is Resource.Error -> {
                        isLoading = false
                        Log.e("Network", "searchBooks: Failed getting books", )
                    }
                    else -> {isLoading = false}
                }

            }catch (exception: Exception){
                isLoading = false
                Log.d("Network", "searchBooks: ${exception.message.toString()}")
            }

        }


    }


}
```

I am using dagger hilt 2.46 version I already tried following stackoverflow answer [Given component holder class packagename.MainActivity does not implement interface dagger.hilt.internal.GeneratedComponent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75256776/given-component-holder-class-packagename-mainactivity-does-not-implement-interfa) and other all answers it did not help I already add AndroidEntryPoint to MainActivity as well and all necessary hilt dependency as well I want to know where exactly I am making mistake

Comment: try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67319542/getting-error-from-creating-a-hilt-viewmodel

Comment: I check this @SyedAhmedJamil did not solve my problem

Comment: @SyedAhmedJamil what do you think any other solutions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed my problem by updating jetpack compose navigation version from 1.0.0 to 1.1.0-alpha01

```
implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.1.0-alpha01")
```

in app.gradle file